# Filter dataframe by first order per customer

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

I would like some help to solve the following problem using Pandas in Python.

I have a dataframe about the customers' transactions - in random order, which contains the following columns, along with datatypes:

- user_id **object**;
- transaction_date **datetime64[ns]**;
- account_creation_date **datetime64[ns]**;
- transaction_id **object**;

I need to find a dataframe that contains all the first (chronological) transactions for every customer. The final dataframe should contain the same columns as the original one.

So far I have tried to use some "group by", together with aggregate functions, but I cannot seem to get the first transaction in chronological order, instead of the first in order of appeareance.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `df.sort_values(['transaction_date']).drop_duplicates('user_id')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you the earliest observation per customer:

```
df_first = df.sort_values('transaction_date').groupby('user_id').head(1)
```